# In question lists, show the date relevant to the sorting method

Tags: feature-request, sorting, android-app, timestamps

In question results list, the dates/timestamps should be shown the same way as they are on the site. I.e., when sorting by newest, then show the "asked" date, but sorting by activity should show the last modified date.

**In other words, show the user the date that the app is actually sorting by.**

(Adding "asked" or "modified" before the date might be good, if space-consuming.)

[image]

---

Example of how the site does it:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Reversed since version.... I forgot. Now, on v1.0.83, it uses "last modified" timestamp for all sorting.

Comment: @AndrewT.      I want to check if this is still an issue on the v1.0.83, as it still shows the initial post date.

Comment: @RSM thanks for reminding me of this issue. On v1.0.85 beta, it seems it's already fixed: "Newest" will show posting time, and "Active" (and the rest of sorting) will show last modified time. Not sure if it's only since this version, or the API (which is the root cause) was fixed...

Comment: @AndrewT.       Ok, I always have it on "Active" and I see the original posting date for all questions. So I don't know if its just the version I have